# ag-Grid RowClassRule not updating after using updateRowData

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm trying to update an ag-Grid row data the following way:

```
this.table.api.updateRowData({
    update: [response.data]
})
```

The updating works fine, the cells get the updated values. However, Ag Grid is not re-evaluating the class of the row. Additionally, I get an error message:

> ag-Grid: could not find data item as object was not found

Here is my rowClassRule:

```
rowClassRules: {
    "row-disabled": function(params) {
        if (params.data.status != 1) {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I get ag Grid to update the class as well? I have tried using: `rowNode.setData()` which was working perfectly (updating the cell value + class) - but I can't use it because it's not refreshing the filters, unfortunately.

Comment: have you implemented `getRowNodeId` method for your grid?

Comment: Did you try api.refreshCells() or api.redrawRows().  "Your preference should be to use refreshCells() over redrawRows()" - ag grid

Answer (score 9):

After setting the new row data, since you are using `rowClass` feature you have to use `api.redrawRows()`

`rowNode.setData()` being an api method is closely tied with ag-grid change detection mechanism and would automatically trigger api.refreshCells() for you. But if you are manually updating the data set, you need to invoke `api.redrawRows()` for styles to change.

As per docs -

> Use redraw row if you want to create the row again from scratch. This
>   is useful when you have changed a property that only gets used when
>   the row is created for the first time such as:
>
> - Whether the row is fullWidth or not.
> - The cellRenderer used for any cell (as this is specified once when    the cell is created).
> - You want to specify different styles for the row via the callbacks    getRowStyle() or getRowClass().

Example here - [redraw nodes](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/#example-redraw-nodes)

Comment: I used it in on the cellValueChanged event and it works. Thanks.